# Different values displayed for .NET CLR Version v4.0.30319

Tags: .net, biztalk, iis-8, biztalk-2013

Can anyone explain the difference between the values displayed below? 
And why one might give errors below and one might not?

[image]

in the IIS list of app pools, it shows as v4.0.30319.

and

[image]

which in the IIS list of app pools shows as v4.0.

If I try to add a new app pool, the only choice is ".NET CLR Version v4.0.30319", but the app pool that is now working for me has the other value.

I had several web service apps that were not working today, but worked a week or two ago.  Maybe installing BizTalk ESB Toolkit, or maybe a Windows update seems to have changed something.  I suddenly started getting one of two errors:

> HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found - The requested content appears to be
>   script and will not be served by the static file handler.

OR

> "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

I got one app to work by doing three things: 
1) Change applicationHostConfig

```
<!-- <add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler" /> -->
<add name="ServiceModel" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="managedHandler,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

2) Changed my app pool to CoreEsbNetworkAppPool

3) Changed that app pools identity to one that would work with BizTalk

This seems like an excessive number of steps to fix, and I have to do similar for my other apps next.

I'm on 64-bit Windows 2012/R2 server, IIS 8.5.9600.16384.
Thus when I first tried the most common solution of aspnet_iisreg -iru, it said

```
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administr
ators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Win
dows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.e
xe command line tool.  For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlin
k/?LinkID=216771.
Finished installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.0).
```

and .NET 4.5 was already turned on the Windows Features.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2015129/error-message-after-you-install-the-net-framework-4-0-could-not-load-t

Comment: @Hans - I think I addressed everything from that page in my question above.